# How to: Playm3u8 files offline in VLC

Tags: vlc, m3u8

I'm using an offline terminal to create an `.m3u8` file but I would like to play it using VLC. Every example so far has shown examples of using m3u8 online but this isn't an option for me. If you can play it offline using VLC how do you do so?

Answer (score 2):

You have to download the playlist from m3u8 to watch it offline and to do that you have to either use youtube-dl or ffmpeg

i would recommend ffmpeg , and the command for downloading the m3u8 file goes like this :-

> ffmpeg -i "here your m3u8 link" -c copy Output.mp4

This will download the highest quality video available in that m3u8 file.
To change quality you can use map command or simply download the m3u8 file and open it with notepad and there you will find links for other resolution.

Answer (score 0):

m3u8 files are just playlists without actual contents, but just URL pointers. Those files are mostly being used these days for HLS.

While you can play the files while offline, you won't see anything unless you are also hosting the referenced Contents.

Comment: I have .m3u8 files and the content .ts files but I'm not sure how I would play them offline because every example i have seen is using a website URL which isn't an option for me unfortunately

Comment: As @feepk pointed out and as described in the [m3u wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U#File_format), your best bet if you have the files locally is to use a local file path (instead of an HTTP URL), relative or absolute.